# To integrate with Silverpop

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

Can anyone guide how to integrate with Silverpop, using OAuth(tokens)?

I referred this link
[connecting to web api using c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20127838/connecting-to-web-api-using-c-sharp)

and I was able to get access token. After this I don't know how to proceed.

Thanks.

Comment: Can someone guide me regarding Silverpop?

Comment: Can anyone help me solve this please

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at my github repo:

https://github.com/marcelluseasley/IBM-Marketing-Cloud-XML-API-Wrapper

It isn't finished, but I started working on an XML API wrapper for the Silverpop API. First of all, if you are trying to integrate with the API, you should be able to contact client support and get a copy of the API PDF.

In any case, you should have a client id, client secret, and refresh token. You will need these three things along with a header value of "refresh_token" for the "grant_type" header key.

So you will first sent a post to https://api(pod number).silverpop.com/oauth/token . This will return an access token in a json dictionary ("access_token").

Any subsequent calls made to the API endpoint (https://api(pod number).silverpop.com/XMLAPI will require that you pass this access token in the header section of your request:

"Authorization:" would be the header key and 
"Bearer: (access token)" would be the header value

Looking at my code will make it clearer if you are using Python. Your best bet is to get a copy of the API documentation. You have to be a Silverpop client to get a copy though.

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Check the follwing:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/758362/SilverPop-Integration

Follow the step by step guide.

Comment: Link no longer supported